# SQL Cast, Case and Count function

Tags: sql, casting, count, case

I am trying to count rows of email opens and divide it by the total email sends and convert this into decimal (so it shows percentage).

I am getting the error: `"An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near ')'."`

I have tried separating the code so I can get the count and case function separately to cast. Cast works without the count/case. Count/case also works independently, it just doesn't seem to work all together. Am I missing something here?

```sql
SELECT
SubscriberKey
,CAST(
 ((COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN PreviousMonth <= 1
                    AND SendType = 'Auto'
                    AND Opened = 1
                    THEN 1
                ELSE NULLEND ))/
        (COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN PreviousMonth <= 1
                    AND SendType = 'Auto')))
AS DECIMAL(18,4)) * 100 AS 'AverageOpen'
FROM Data
GROUP BY SubscriberKey

An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this using `SUM(CASE)`.  Note two things:

- The 1.0 so the division is not integers (which can be an issue in some databases.
- No `else` in the denominator to avoid divide-by-zero

I also left out the `cast()`:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
       (SUM(CASE WHEN PreviousMonth <= 1 AND
                      SendType = 'Auto'
                      Opened = 1
                 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 
            END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN PreviousMonth <= 1 AND
                      SendType = 'Auto'
                 THEN 1   -- no else so no divide by 0
            END)
       ) * 100 AverageOpen
FROM Data
GROUP BY SubscriberKey;
```

You code may be failing because of `NULLEND` is not recognized in SQL.

Comment: Would I not need COUNT because I need to count the number of rows with the CASE criterias?

Comment: @s3329893 . . . `SUM(1)` = `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve here is to get the `average` of `opened = 1 divided by all`.

```
SELECT cast((t1.Opened/t1.OverAll) as decimal(18,4)) * 100.00 as 'AverageOpen'
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SubscriberKey
        , SUM(CASE WHEN PreviousMonth <= 1 AND SendType = 'Auto' AND Opened = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Opened,
        , SUM(CASE WHEN PreviousMonth <= 1 AND SendType = 'Auto' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OverAll
    FROM Data 
    GROUP BY SubscriberKey) as t1
```